# Combinations as generalized sequences

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs

I've been experimenting with combinations. Specifically, I've found some patterns:

The sequence $n \choose 2$ has a constant second difference and the sequence $n \choose 3$ has a constant third difference. I imagine this pattern continues.

Specifically, I was able to derive the sequence $a_{n+1} = a_n + n$ for $n \choose 2$ and have not derived one for $n \choose 3$ (I'm not sure how to approach this one).

What mathematical property gives way to what I am witnessing? I had not thought combinations could be calculated without multiplication or factorials.

Comment: Observe that $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!} = \frac{n(n - 1)(n - 2) \cdots (n - k + 1)}{k!}$$ is a polynomial of degree $k$.  A polynomial of degree $k$ has a constant $k$th difference.

Comment: Do you have a textbook I could look into this for @N.F.Taussig ?

Answer (score 1):

This phenomena that you are experiencing is simply due to [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle). The entry of the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ row and $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ column is given by $\begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix}$. You are finding a pattern along some diagonal of this triangle!